Vue how to mock a ref value
I am writing a modal component in vue 3:
// MyModal.vue

<script setup>
  const emit = defineEmits(['close'])
  const modalDialog = ref(null)

  const close = () => {
    emit('close')
    modalDialog.value.close()
  }
  defineExpose({
    close
  })
</script>

<template>
  <dialog ref="modalDialog">
    <h1>My Modal</h1>
    <slot />
  </dialog>
</template>

I am writing a test to cover the modal component's close() method. For this, I am trying to mock the ref and manually calling the close() method, but I am getting error modalDialog.value.close is not a function when executing the test. The component works well in the browser, but not in vitest.
// MyModal.spec.js

const closeMock = vi.fn()
describe('MyModal', () => {
  test('close()', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyModal)
    wrapper.vm.modalDialog.value = {
      close: closeMock
    }

    wrapper.vm.close()
    expect(closeMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})

Here is an example of how I use the modal component:
<script setup>
import MyModal from './MyModal.vue'
const myModal = ref()

const openMyModal = () => {
  myModal.value.open()
}

const closeMyModal = () => {
  myModal.value.close()
}
</script>

<template>
  <my-modal ref="myModal" >
    <template #default>
      <MyComponent @close:modal="closeMyModal" />
    </template>
  </my-modal>
</template>


Don't try to mock the internals of a component built with composition api, it's not supposed to be tested this way. In this case you need to mock dialog component to match your expectations

<dialog> is a native HTML componnent here, not a Vue component. I suspect it's related to the vitest environment used like jsdom that may not mock this element correctly?

The fix was the following:
https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3294#issuecomment-1196577616
beforeAll(() => {
  HTMLDialogElement.prototype.show = vi.fn();
  HTMLDialogElement.prototype.showModal = vi.fn();
  HTMLDialogElement.prototype.close = vi.fn();
});

test('close()', () => {
  wrapper.vm.close()
  expect(HTMLDialogElement.prototype.close).toHaveBeenCalled()
})


